# ¿Cómo crear una posición nueva en joomla o themler?

Tags: joomla3, theme

Ya intenté buscando información y sé que primero se crea la posición en los archivos del **template** hasta ahí sé, ya no sé que prosigue.

Como les indico que quiero que esa posición sea vertical.

¿Cómo lo creo en **themler**?

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Declaring_module_positions

Comment: Parece que aún sigues sin entender la pregunta, el enlace que adjuntas no es para la aplicación en cuestión.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes seguir los pasos descritos en el siguiente video:
http://answers.themler.com/articles/3878/how-to-add-a-new-wide-joomla-module-position-video

En el siguiente enlace puedes encontrar más información acerca de esta aplicación:
http://answers.themler.com/categories/3919/joomla-4

Comment: Esta respuesta es realmente muy mala, debería ser un comentario, en el mejor de los casos.

Comment: es una respuesta del 2016 @Shaz

Comment: @gbianchi creo que la antigüedad no le quita lo mala, digo yo.

Comment: @Shaz ¿Por qué es una mala respuesta?, no entiendo porque dirigir al usuario a la documentación oficial de la aplicación y del tema en cuestión es malo.

Comment: @AlejandroVega ¿es en serio la pregunta? Han pasado cuatro años y no has aprendido cómo funciona StackOverflow. ¡Todo un récord!